# UFT pass value to Jenkins Console Output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hp-uft

I have some UFT scripts in Jenkins. Jenkins shows me that the build was successful or failed. I can find detailed information about build in "UFT Report" in Jenkins.

Is there any way to pass parameters (like "order ID") from UFT build to Jenkins Console Output?
Or send it in e-mail notification?

Comment: You should be able to use Reporter.ReportEvent within your UFT script to have the value output into the report?

Answer (score 0):

The hard way is to use WINAPI. UFT is spawned from the Jenkins Agent and it inherits its' in, out and err streams. In UFT you can use the Extern Object to access WINAPI functions. Theoretically it's possible (I never did it however).

The "workaroundish" way would be the good old file. Dump your content to a file, make Jenkins pick it up or email it to somebody. (Of course your pipeline has to know where to look for the file, and your scripts should create it exactly there)